# Max each row from equation

Tags: r

I have data that has different values  that looks something like this:

```
PRICE   TIME    VALUE ID
1000     10      14   1
4000     20      34   2
3000     30      5    3
5000     10      15   NA
2000     20      14   4
4000     30      11   NA
```

I want to add a new column called `MAX` containing maximum between result of the two column calculation for each row:

1. price x time x 5
2. price x value x 4.5

I tried to use

```
df = df %>% mutate(Max =  ifelse((str_length(ID)>0, max(price * time * 5,price * value * 4.5),""))
```

But each row return NA

Comment: Try something like `mutate(Max = pmax(PRICE * TIME * 5, PRICE * VALUE * 4.5))`

Comment: If you want to only calculate among those whose `ID` is no `NA`, you can do: `df %>% mutate(max = if_else(is.na(ID), NA, pmax(PRICE * TIME * 5, PRICE * VALUE * 4.5)))`

Comment: In your code it seems like you only want the max value if the ID is not `NA`. You could try something like this to assign Max to `NA` in such cases: `mutate(Max = pmax(PRICE * TIME * 5, PRICE * VALUE * 4.5) * sign(ID))`. sign(ID) is `NA` for `NA`, 1 for every number > 1 and -1 for every number < 1.